# Как установить YII?

Tags: php, yii

Здравствуйте. Помогите установить yii. На сайте и в доках ничего толком не описано.

> Скачайте дистрибутив закинте в корневую папку

А как сгенерировать проект с yiic? Не хочется бросать это дело, есть цель написать свой скрипт. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобратся!

Answer (score 1):

**yiic** — скрипт для Linux/Unix;

**yiic.bat** — скрипт для Windows.

Фактически, вы генерируете каркас приложения, скелетон. Делаете вы это один раз, потом его можно доработать и таскать куда угодно для нового проекта.

Собственно мануал: http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/quickstart.first-app

Answer (score 0):

[Создание первого приложения](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/quickstart.first-app)